# How can we get share count for posts on a page

Tags: facebook, count, share

I'm tyring to get the number of shares per post on a business page. I have read about the link_stats table which seems to have share_count for links. But I'm unable to find the share count per post. I can get number of comments and likes per post in the streams table. but share count seems to be missing. Please let me know if there is any other way to get share count per post in a page. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`shares` is provided as a connection on the /ID/feed endpoint, which means that you will be able to see the share count for posts in your /feed for your Page. This should really also be in the connections of an individual post, I suggest filing a feature request in the [Facebook Bug Tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) for that.

Comment: Looks like someone is looking into it now: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1460378860850862/